# CSS3 in Aptana AIR

Tags: air, css, aptana

How can I use CSS3 in Aptana Studio 2.0 with the AIR plugin? I want to build an AIR application with CSS3 (advanced), but it doesn't work correctly. I want to use like the Safari/Google Chrome type of CSS3.

ORIGINAL: [Here](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/1240-css3-in-air-plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I got it working with the AIR beta 2.0.